# chrome extension problems in content_script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have my  Main.js file in  content_scripts. Main.js file provides a button and when the user click the html page is saved with reloading the html page.
But when user clicks button for a second time the button is not working as some of the previous values where set when the button were clicked first time.
Is there any way in chrome than Main.js will be automatically reload or execute as fresh script on every click.
Windows.onload methos is not working on my Main.js file so how i solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible you can use `location.reload` function